# trying to compare time using string compare

Tags: c, string, time, compare, time.h

i am building this code that adds 10 seconds to the current time and then compare the updated time with the actual time and when they match , there's a message to be printed. 
here's my code . can anybody tell me where i am going wrong.
here is my code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <time.h>

    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
            time_t timeNow;
            time_t timeAct;
            struct tm* time_info;
            time(&timeNow);
            time(&timeAct);
            time_info = localtime(&timeNow);
            char timeStr[sizeof"HH:MM:SS"];
            char timeN[sizeof"HH:MM:SS"];

            strftime(timeStr, sizeof(timeStr), "%H:%M:%S", time_info);
            printf("Time now: %s\n", timeStr);


            timeNow += 10;
            time_info = localtime(&timeNow);
            strftime(timeStr, sizeof(timeStr), "%H:%M:%S", time_info);
            printf("New time: %s\n", timeStr);

            time_info=localtime(&timeAct);
            strftime(timeN, sizeof(timeN), "%H:%M:%S", time_info);
            printf("time Actual: %s\n",timeN);


            while(1)
            {
                    if(strcmp(timeStr,timeN) == 0)
                    {
                            printf("hi");
                    }
            }
}
```

i think there is problem with string compare . not sure though!

here is the output:

```
Time now: 12:41:17
New time: 12:41:27
time Actual: 12:41:17
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Not that your `while(1)` loop never breaks.

Comment: yeah i knw it needs a break; problem is : i can't get my "hi" printed.  @Marievi

Comment: One more comment : you don't need the `while` loop, as you compare the same strings all the time and they are not going to change inside the loop (unless you plan something else).

Comment: Did you do basic debugging ? For example printing `timeStr` and `timeN` right before `strcmp`?. What's the purpose of the `while(1)` loop ?

Comment: Why *would* `timeStr`, ever equal `timeN`? And why do you think that the `while` loop will increase the likelihood of this happening? Seems that the best thing to do is for you to use your debugger.

Answer (score 5):

You set the "actual" time string (`timeN`) once, before the loop. You need to set it continuously in the loop, or it will never change.